# MATLAB error: You cannot specify 'stable' and 'sorted' with 'first' and 'last'

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have two column vectors X and Y of the same size derived by following Matlab code:

```
mask = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ecpw.png');
separation = bwulterode(mask,'euclidean',[0 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 0]).*mask; 
[X, Y] = find(separation);
```

I want to remove the repeating values in X and also their correspondent values in Y without rearranging the order of elements. So I use the `unique` function with the `'stable'` argument:

```
% 'stable' argument preserves ordering
[Xfixed, ind] = unique(X, 'stable');
% ind now holds the indices of the unique elements
Yfixed = Y(ind);
```

But, I want the `unique` function to return the indices of the last occurrence of each unique value, and  when I use `'last'` argument with `unique` funstion:

```
[Xfixed, ind] = unique(X, 'stable', 'last');
```

I get this error:

```
You cannot specify 'stable' and 'sorted' with 'first' and 'last'.
```

How I could remove the first occurrence of the repeating elements in X, and Y? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `last`-option and restore the order manually:

```
[~,ind]=unique(X,'last')
ind=sort(ind)
Yfixed = Y(ind);
Xfixed = X(ind);
```